# Why is the RSA exponentiation function a permutation (i.e. a bijection) over $\mathbb{Z}^*_N$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, roots, cryptography

Why is the  RSA exponentiation function a permutation (i.e. a bijection) over $\mathbb{Z}^*_N$? My doubt was specifically why, when raising to the power of the decryption key d we get a unique number x? My concern is specifically on the roots $x^{e^{-1}}=x^{1/e}$ being unique (which isn't the "normal" case for polynomial equations like that). Why is it that if we have $x^{e}$, why don't we have e different roots for $x^{e} \pmod {N}$?

I do understand that $ed = 1 \pmod N$ and that therefore:

$$x^{ed} = x^{ed \pmod {\phi(N)}} = x \pmod N$$

But what I did not understand is why the rules that we had for roots having e different roots that satisfied an equation like:

$$x^e = y \pmod N$$

Don't apply anymore. Why is there not a different $x' \neq x$ such that $x^e = (x')^e \pmod N$. What is the fundamental difference between the two setting? And why does that difference make it such that the  RSA exponentiation function now has a unique correspondence between the two sets?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

A polynomial of degree $e$ has *at most* $e$ roots. The result that it has *exactly* $e$ roots (counting multiplicities) is only valid over an [algebraically closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraically_closed_field) field, and $\mathbb{Z}_N$ is not algebraically closed.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, but then why does it have to be a one to one mapping? It could have an unknown number of roots or none, how is it unique? Btw, thnx for ur response. :)

Comment: The simple answer to that one is that the inversion formula proves it. It is not one-to-one on the whole field, thought. Only on the invertible elements.

Comment: The thing that still confuses me is in the group $\mathbb{Z}^*_N$ for example, has that p-1/2 of its elements are quadratic residues. However, these quadratic residues do have 2 square roots. But here $Z^*_N$ isn't a field either and it does have that each quadratic residue has two roots.

Comment: $e$ must be coprime to $\phi(n)$, which is even (unless $n = 2$). So $e$ won't be two, and quadratic residues won't come into play.